# Import .scss file into .js file in Reactenvironment

Tags: css, reactjs, grid, components, jsx

> Global.scss

/src/styles/global/Global.scss

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
}
```

> Meta.js

/src/components/Meta.js

This file contains the import statements for the `.scss` file
`import "../styles/global/Global.scss";`

> index.js

/src/pages/index.js

This file contains the import statement for the component `import Meta from '../components/Meta';`

Followed by

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Meta />
      <Header />
      <p>Hello world!</p>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

> Footer.js

/src/components/Footer.js

```
class Footer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <footer className="container grid">
                <div className="footer-primary-nav">
                    <p>Primary Nav</p>
                </div>
            </footer>
        );
    }
}
export default Footer;
```

The class `.grid` isn't being loaded into the `Footer.js` from the `Global.scss` file.

On paper, I thought this would be working, but the `.grid` styling isn't being loaded on the page.Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it should, could you change it to css and try it again.

Comment: I wouldn’t be doing that. That’s cutting corners. I’m teaching myself as I’m doing the project and it’ll have to be a .scss file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the server just needed to be reset / turned off. Looked at yesterday and it was working as expected.